# Sort chart in qlik based on another chart / field / KPI

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

How Can i sort a diagramm (bar diagramm) based on a KPI / field, which is not in this diagramm, for example I have:

[image]

And want to sort "Kennzahlen" with a different Sum of another field which is not in this chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you scroll down on the properties menu on the right, underneath the "daten" group you'll see the sorting tab

[image]

Then you can turn off the other sorting options.

[image]

and enable ***by expression***

[image]

Then you can add any expression you like